# Вывод None при парсинге сайта на Python

Tags: python, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup, bs4

Вот мой код:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

URL = 'https://yandex.com.am/weather/tula?via=srp&lat=54.193122&lon=37.617348'

response = requests.get(URL)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
temp = bs.find('span', 'temp__value temp__value_with-unit')
print(temp)
```

Пытаюсь парсить сайт Яндекс погоды. Хочу вывести элемент, в котором указано количество градусов, но вместо него получаю None. Класс элемента вроде бы указываю правильно (прикрепляю скриншот). В чем может быть ошибка?
[image: Тег элемента]

Comment: print(response.url) https://yandex.com.am/showcaptcha?cc=1&mt=A3092C3EC54932681E20DBE254508B7CED3F623DDC796B267C9CCFD59FF883AD013A&retpath=aHR0cHM6Ly95YW5kZXguY29tLmFtL3dlYXRoZXIvdHVsYT92aWE9c3JwJmxhdD01NC4xOTMxMjImbG9uPTM3LjYxNzM0OA%2C%2C_2af3ea1f3288e59dd56f27d431531418&t=2/1668879422/8b25560720f3abbbc2ef7fe2996e4862&u=3bdbb0f1-18719b66-583f81b0-f7fb3b0b&s=304f89d92c913807e4091a0f3bc91da9

Comment: В том, что возвращает yandex.com.am  нет 'temp__value temp__value_with-unit'

Comment: @Виктор а как мне в таком случае получить содержимое span'а?

Comment: Передать в параметрах запроса user-agent и cookie

Comment: По всей видимости страница динамическая и надо использовать Selenium, либо дебажить запросы в Chrome и искать запрос к данным

Comment: Эта (выделенная Вами строка) появляется после Fetch/XHR запроса, а когда Вы читаете просто страницу без выполнения JS скриптов - её нет